# Issue with combining InEqualities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have the following two inequalities:
$$\begin{align*}
    8x  &\gt 12y\\
    12y &\gt 15z
\end{align*}$$
Now the book states that we need to line up the inequalities as such
$$\begin{array}{rcccccl}
      0  &<&  15z\\
          && 15z  &<&  12y\\
          & &     &  &  12y  &<&  8x\\
\end{array}$$
Hence we get $$ 0 < 15z < 12y  < 8x $$

Now my question is how did the book get  the following
$$\begin{array}{rcccccl}
      0  &<&  15z\\
           && 15z  &<&  12y\\
          &&       &&  12y  &<&  8x
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thats what i want to know how did the book get  $$ 0<15z $$ , I could only come up with $$ 15z < 12y < 8x $$

Comment: The $0\lt 15z$ part is not sensible, since nothing in the two given inequalities implies that $0 \lt 15z$. As to the others, $p \gt q$ says the same thing as $q \lt p$. So for example the given inequality $8x \gt 12y$ can be rewritten as $12y \lt 8x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $12y\lt 8x$, because that is the first inequality you have; it appears last in the large display.

You also know that $15z\lt 12y$, because that is the second inequality you have; it appears in the middle of the large display.

And, presumably, you know that $z$ is positive, so that $15z$ is also positive, $15z\gt 0$.

So: $0$ is smaller than $15z$; and $15z$ is smaller than $12y$; and $12y$ is smaller than $8x$. That's the three inequalities that appear, only they are indented to make it clear how they fit together.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a compound inequality such as $1 < x < 2$, you are using a tacit Boolean `and`.  So, for example, 
$$ (1 < x < 2) \Leftrightarrow ((1 < x) \wedge (x < 2)).$$
This is how you should parse it.